# Creating docker image from existing docker image and running new docker image

Tags: docker

I created a simple docker image, calling it a base-image:

```
FROM centos:7
ENTRYPOINT [ "ls" ]
```

I built docker image out of it; and image id --> `bc8d9c9f28eb`

Now, I wanted to act this image bc8d9c9f28eb as "base" image to create other docker images, for example:

```
FROM bc8d9c9f28eb
ENTRYPOINT [ "ls -la" ]
```

And made docker image, and after doing docker build, for example, the docker image id came as --> "2b748f91b70f"

The "base" image when I run, it works fine, for example:

docker run bc8d9c9f28eb

However, the second image which I build using "bc8d9c9f28eb" as a basis, it isn't working.

docker run 2b748f91b70f

Getting the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls -la\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I am building all these images locally.

Am I doing anything wrong? My intention is to create a "base" image from which I can create "other" images.

Comment: The image layering is correct, but you're trying to run a command `"ls -la"` as one word, with a space in the command name; not a command and its argument.  You need to split up the JSON-array syntax into two words.  (I'd also generally recommend `CMD` over `ENTRYPOINT`; what happens if you `docker run --rm -it bc8d9c9f28eb /bin/bash` to get a debugging shell?)

Comment: @DavidMaze: Thx for your suggestion. I will try it. out. I was concerned if layering is correct or not.